# Not called didSelectRowAtIndexPath of UITableview in popupView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, popover

I am Opening popupView having Tableview inside it on textField onEditing event.

I am setting DataSource & Delegate both for tableview.
I have set this much property for Tableview

1) AllowSelection = Yes

2) userInterectionEnabled = Yes

3) tableview.layer.zposition = 1

4) [self.view bringSubViewToFront: tableview]

Here's the code..

```
UITableView *tblCompany = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  [UtilClass getScreenWidth]-[UtilClass getScreenWidth]/4, 200)];
tblCompany.dataSource = self;
tblCompany.delegate = self;
tblCompany.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
tblCompany.allowsSelection=YES;
tblCompany.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.popOver addSubView:tblCompany];
```

**My Problem**

I have many controls like buttons & labels in my viewController.
When i edit to my textfield the popup opens over the buttons.

When i try to click on the cell of tableView, it does not called `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but i clicks to the button behind it.

> Note: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,`numberOfRowsInSection`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` these all are working fine, so there is no problem with `DataSource` or `Delegate`
>
> Note: Not used any `Gesture` in my viewController.

I think there is some problem with layer so i apply zPosition also , but doen't work..

**Edit**
I am just making popOver view.hidden = true or false on textField Editing..

is there any solution?

Comment: you need to explain how the table view is presented / added to the screen and when that is done in relation to the other code you have shown

Comment: It seems that your tableview goes behind your button. When you display UITableview, use `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:YOUR_TABLEVIEW];`

Comment: Also check in Debug view Hierarchy .

Comment: @Wain, check My edit

Comment: @Hima, Right Hima, I too thinks so. but i have applied `bringSubviewToFront` & how to debug view Hierarchy?

Comment: See image in answer.

Comment: try to disable the user interaction of previous view/ button when the table view is presented.  you can enable it again when you dismiss the table.

Comment: @MilanGupta, I tried this too but still TableView Cell is not yet clicked..

Comment: do you have any UIButton in your Tableviewcell?

Comment: no i simple set tableviewcell.labeltext.text only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your tableview is in the front while running the app.

[image]

Comment: Can't you select row in Debug view Hierarchy also?